# Is is possible to publish a stream from recordRTC to a tokbox Session?

Tags: webrtc, opentok, tokbox, recordrtc

I want to capture screen (or a canvas) with recordRTC and send it to tokbox session as a stream instead of a stream from camera, microphone or sharescreen.

What I want is subscribers gets a stream that is the record of a canvas of the other peer (the publisher). Is there a way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This blog post details how you can publish a custom MediaStream into an OpenTok Session. https://tokbox.com/blog/camera-filters-in-opentok-for-web/

It's not officially supported just yet you have to do a bit of a hack.